# Best design to show a post isn't free?

Tags: interaction-design, human-interface-guideline

I've a Q&A *(question and answer)* website like SE. In my website, some of questions have a cost to see their answers, I mean they aren't free. Now I'm trying to make a different in the UI between free questions and non-free ones.

Currently they have the same UI except a blue-box under non-free questions which contains the cost of that question. Something like this:

[image]

Ok, **what's the problem?** That bule-box *(which is the only different between them)* will be hidden after marking an answer as the accepted one. I mean that blue-box goes under that answer. So the user cannot understand such a question is free or not at a glance. He needs to scroll and looks for whether is there that blue-box?

Anyway I need to make a constant different between free and non-free questions. Any suggestion?

**Note:** I can simply change the color of its title *(and give it a tiny `text-shadow`)* when the question isn't free like this:

But I'm doubt it is a good idea.

[image]

Comment: For a paid solution, how is the question displayed? Is it completely hidden, or does it still take up space on the page and is just blocked out? What is the blue box that you are speaking about, is it the one with the number '200' in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to show them:

1. **An approach you can look at is blurring the background** providing an notification that payment or subscription is needed to view this.

ExpertsExchange uses this to grant access to specific solutions as shown below

[image]

Similarly [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) uses this approach where the background is blurred out and a notification mentions that you need to login to see the post.

[image]

2. Another option would be to use something like [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/) **where you explicitly mention which answers are paid and make them non-clickable**

[image]